# Does C# linq have something similar to SummaryStatistics?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

In Java I can do this:

```
List<String> stringList = getRandomStrings(100_000, 1000);
IntSummaryStatistics stats =
                stringList.stream()
                        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                        .mapToInt(String::length)
                        .summaryStatistics();

System.out.println(stats);
```

The output is:

```
IntSummaryStatistics{count=100000, sum=49868013, min=0, average=498.680130, max=999}
```

Does linq have the same functionality? Or do I have to calculate everything seperately?

Java does this in one go, and it looks like in C# you have to calculate all the constituents `Average()`, `Count()`, `Sum()`, `Min()` and `Max()` separately.

Comment: what is summaryStatistics do in java

Comment: @Eldho calculates count, sum, min, average, max of a stream.

Comment: No, atleast i dont think linq doesn't provide output like this. You can have method like summary statistics and use that.

Comment: How exactly do you sum and average strings?

Comment: @juharr you don't, in the example above I first map strings to ints, where the int is the length of a given string.

Comment: At the very least you don't have to do average since you can get that from sum and count.

Comment: @juharr yes, but that's besides the point.

Comment: @Coder-Man It's also very trivial to write a single loop that will calculate all those values.  Why Java bothers to junk up their code base with stuff like this is beyond me.

Comment: @juharr I agree, but since I am not very good at C#, I don't understand how that will be parallelized, if I want to use `AsParallel()` for example. Like I write my own extension method for this, and then what? How does it get parallelized?

Comment: Why didn't you ask about that.  I mean it seems like that method in Java would potentially have issues with palatalization as well depending on how it's implemented.

Comment: @juharr In java there's a new interface called `Spliterator` that can split a stream into several substreams and then combine them, when all the parallel operations are finished, however, I don't understand how C# does that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not aware of anything built into .NET that does the equivalent, but you can easily implement it yourself using `Aggregate` from LINQ. This meets your requirement of only enumerating the source collection once.

```
var ints = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 677, 8 };

var summary = ints.Aggregate(
    seed: (
        count: 0, 
        sum: 0, 
        min: int.MaxValue, 
        max: int.MinValue),
    func: (acc, x) => (
        count: acc.count + 1, 
        sum: acc.sum + x, 
        min: Math.Min(acc.min, x), 
        max: Math.Max(acc.max, x)),
    resultSelector: acc => (
        acc.count, 
        acc.sum, 
        acc.min, 
        acc.max, 
        avg: (double)acc.sum / acc.count));

Console.WriteLine(
    $"count = {summary.count}, " +
    $"sum = {summary.sum}, " +
    $"min = {summary.min}, " +
    $"max = {summary.max}, " +
    $"average = {summary.avg}");
```

If your collection is very large and you want to parallelize its processing, you can use this overload:

```
var summary = ints.AsParallel().Aggregate(
    seed: (
        count: 0,
        sum: 0,
        min: int.MaxValue,
        max: int.MinValue),
    updateAccumulatorFunc: (acc, x) => (
        count: acc.count + 1,
        sum: acc.sum + x,
        min: Math.Min(acc.min, x),
        max: Math.Max(acc.max, x)),
    combineAccumulatorsFunc: (acc1, acc2) => (
        count: acc1.count + acc2.count,
        sum: acc1.sum + acc2.sum,
        min: Math.Min(acc1.min, acc2.min),
        max: Math.Max(acc1.max, acc2.max)),
    resultSelector: acc => (
        acc.count,
        acc.sum,
        acc.min,
        acc.max,
        avg: (double)acc.sum / acc.count));
```